# Inevitable variadic templates in GCC (used with CUDA)?

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda, thrust

I was trying out some CUDA/Thrust code on Linux/GCC and wanted to use some TR1 libraries, when I noticed something peculiar: Most libraries will invariably pull in `tr1_impl/type_traits` (4.4) or just `type_traits` (4.6), and that header will always contain variadic templates, like so:

```
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
    : public true_type { };
```

However, these headers also get used when I run GCC in C++98 or C++03 mode! How can this work?

The actual problem I encountered is that the CUDA toolchain doesn't recognize C++0x constructions, and `cudafe++` (the CUDA front end, i.e. the program that separates the joint source code into host and device source code) rightly aborts with an error when encountering the variadic template parameter.

So... how can GCC support and rely on variadic templates in non-0x dialects of C++? And is there a way to obtain a genuine C++03 version of TR1?

Comment: They can't do that in TR1 mode. Bet there is a lot of specializations of is_function for 0, 1, 2, 3, etc arguments.

Comment: @Bo: No, have a look, I triple checked and ran it through the preprocessor and all -- the final preprocessed source in `std=c++98` mode contains `<typename ..._ArgTypes>` -- and that thing compiles! (Try including `<tr1/random>` for instance.)

Comment: Anonymous downvoter: Care to explain your objection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp, an implementation is not required to provide headers. It's required that an `#include <stuff>` does The Right Thing. So that means that *if* an implementation decides to use headers for this functionality, it's not required that those headers be conforming C++. And in fact GCC has supported variadic templates as an extension for quite some time.

Furthermore, I can't help but notice

```
#pragma GCC system header
```

in the `<tr1/random>` header that you mention. [GCC will treat the file specially](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html), and e.g. not report <s>errors</s> warnings in it. I would have thought using an extension in conforming mode can easily be turned into an error so I'm not sure what's going on but at least legally it's an option.

There's also the special status of TR1, which is not binding. On my implementation as far I can tell the only C++03 header that includes `<type_traits>` is `<functional>` and it properly only does that in C++0x mode (i.e. the rest of the time it's a valid C++03 file via preprocessing, unlike `<tr1/random>`). (I didn't check for other cases though.)

Comment: Hm, the implementation isn't required to provide any particular details of the *standard library*, but I was hoping that there'd be a free-standing C++98/03 version of TR1 somewhere so that I could use that with the CUDA toolchain... good find about the pragma!

Comment: @Kerrek Would you be surprised if I told you that there is such a thing as [Boost.TR1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html)? I could have told you that in chat a long time ago ;)!

Comment: I hadn't dared think about making Boost work with CUDA, but perhaps this may be my only hope :-)